# Swift Index out of Range at cellForRowAtIndexPath with two calls for getDataInBackground

Tags: swift, parse-platform, tableview, indexoutofrangeexception, cell-formatting

I was having a problem where my app was crashing and giving the Index out of Range error, but after I eliminated the function to get imageFiles in background, `imageFiles[indexPath.row].getDataInBackground` the tableView runs normally. I think the problem was that two `getDataInBackground`calls were confusing it.

However, I still need to download the data for imageFiles, so I'm wondering if anyone has a solution for how I can do that within cellForRowAtIndexPath. Any help is much appreciated:)

```
   override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "userPhotoFeedCell", for: indexPath) as! FeedCell

    if PFUser.current()?.objectId != nil {

        cell.userUsername.text = PFUser.current()?.username

    }


    //downloades images and items to populate user post
    postImageFiles[indexPath.row].getDataInBackground { (data, error) in

        if let userPostImageData = data {

            let downloadedUserPostImage = UIImage(data: userPostImageData)

            cell.userFeedPhoto.image = downloadedUserPostImage

        }


    }

    /* IF THIS ISN't COMMENTED APP GIVES INDEX OUT OF RANGE CRASH
    //downloads images for user profile pic
      imageFiles[indexPath.row].getDataInBackground { (data, error) in

     if let imageData = data {

     let downloadedImage = UIImage(data: imageData)

     cell.userProfilePic.image = downloadedImage

     }


     }
    */

    cell.postLocation.text = postLocation[indexPath.row]

    cell.postCaption.text = postCaptions[indexPath.row]

    cell.userFeedPhoto.image = UIImage(named: "OrangeFuego")

    cell.userProfilePic.image = UIImage(named: "usericon.png")

    return cell

}
```

Comment: what is postImageFiles? image url array?

Comment: postImageFiles is a PFFile. so var postImageFiles = [PFFile]()

Answer (score 0):

If it is feasible to load the image using URL, you can make use of SDWebImage library, it downloads the images in the background, has options to set a place holder image as well until the original image is fetched. It also provides options for caching the images.
Here is the link for the library:
https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

Comment: Well would that work for a PFFile? Because postImageFiles is an array that holds [PFFiles](), and I'm running a query to download them from Parse above.

Comment: @FinnWolff Havent tried this library for PFFiles to be frank. Seems parse files have their own representation, do give it a try.

Comment: I'll give it a try but using getDataInBackground definitely works, I just can't call it twice without an error, so getting around that so that I can download the data for both imageFiles and postImageFiles is my main issue